# application.transpose error on startup

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

The code below has worked until my most recent update to it in. It still does work, but for some reason, it errors when opening it on a new PC if you have to click Enabling Editing. If you Enable Editing, end the routine, and close the spreadsheet, it works from there. I am just trying to understand what might be causing the hiccup on the initial open after Enabling Editing.

The code (please note that "Mnger_Tags" is a named group defined in the spreadsheet):

```
Dim Mnger As Variant, MngerCheck As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Determine User/Manager
Mnger = Application.Transpose(Range("Mnger_Tags").Value)
MngerCheck = LCase(Environ("UserName"))

If IsInArray(MngerCheck, Mnger) Then
    frmMngerCheck.Show
    MngerCheck = frmMngerCheck.MngerCheck
    Unload frmMngerCheck
End If
```

The Error:

Takes place on line "Mnger = Application.Transpose(Range("Mnger_Tags").Value)"

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

The goal:

The first line of code is meant to take whatever names are listed in that named range (Mnger_Tags) and create the array Mnger.
The code will then check if any value in the array Mnger match the UserName (MngerCheck).

I hope this is clear enough. This is my first post. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: you could make sure users or new pcs have `protected view` off or `have trusted document locations` [set up](http://www.thrivenetworks.com/blog/2011/05/25/turn-off-enable-editing-in-microsoft-office-2010/)

Comment: Hey Scott, thank you for the suggestion. You are absolutely right. My goal here, though, really is to understand what might be causing the break in the first place. If it is an issue with timing due to load/lag after "Enable Editing" or some other general good practice approach that I could start practicing.

Comment: Have you read up on what happens when `Protected View` is on? When it's on you cannot make edits or changes to the workbook (and apparently this means loading Ranges into an Array in VBA!). So, even though the code fires on the `Workbook_Open` event, because the workbook is protected from edits, the code stops on that line. If you just had a simple MsgBox that popped up there, it would probably work. I think the only way is to edit the `Protected View` settings, first.